# How to load images from folders to train a CNN in Flux library of Julia?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, julia, conv-neural-network, flux.jl

I am trying to write a CNN (U-Net) in Flux ML Library of Julia. However the first hurdle that I am facing is, how to load images from folder to train the model. I have searched the Internet extensively for any method, but no luck. All the examples on the internet for CNN in Flux, use library functions to import pre-existing data-sets like  MNIST dataset. Actually all the examples, use a library functions to load this dataset. Please someone tell me, how to load custom image dataset from folders to train a CNN model written in Flux Julia.
The directory structure of the dataset is as follows:-
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ndu.png)

Comment: If you can use keras or tensorflow libraries inside flux, then ``ImageDataGenerator`` is what you want. I think you can use like this: ``using PyCall
ImageDataGenerator = pyimport("keras").preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator
train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)
train_generator = train.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size = (150, 150), batch_size = 20, class_mode = "binary")``

Comment: Actually, I am not allowed to use PyCall in my Internship. Is there another way to do it using Julia. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the official docs, the train=MNIST.Images() returns an multi-dim array 60000X28x28, and this is fed into the model for training. Will 'train_generator' be compatible with the flux?

Comment: Are you asking how to load a directory of image files into Julia? If you knew how to do that, would you know how to present the data you have loaded to Flux?

Answer (score 0):

The Images package (https://juliaimages.org/latest/install/) will not load an entire folder of images automatically. So here is code to load all images inside the folder:

```
using Images

function load_images(path::String)
    img_paths = readdir(path)
    imgs = []
    for img_path in img_paths
        push!(imgs, load(string(path,img_path)))
    end
    return imgs
end
```

Comment: The whole function can be simplified to: `imgs = [load(img) for img in readdir(path, join = true)]`